# How can I make this function that returns promise not block the other codes?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new to Promise. This is my code

```
  function heavyProcess(){

    var ts = + new Date();
    while((+ new Date() - 2000) < ts ){
      //2 second delay to simulate lengthy process
    }
    console.log('after 2 seconds');

    return Promise.resolve("Done");
  }

  console.log("START");
  heavyProcess().then(function(resolve){
    console.log(resolve);
  });
  console.log("END");
```

It's output is

```
START
after 2 seconds
END
Done
```

How can I make it this way? I don't want a call to a heavy process blocks the next code.

```
START
END
after 2 seconds
Done
```

I've been reading about Promise but I seem can't make this work.

Comment: What is the `2 second delay`?

Comment: i just want to simulate long process time

Comment: You might want to read about web workers

Comment: I tried to pass a function inside `Promise.resolve(function(){console.log('DOne')});` but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
    var p = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('after 2 seconds');
resolve("Done");
  }, 2000);
});

console.log("START");
p().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
console.log("END");
```

Comment: yes, this code outputs my expected result but it's using setTimeout. I want to simulate a call to a lengthy process asynchronously without blocking execution of the next code

Comment: Then you should use web workers as @samsonthehero has said